# baseObject data lost on post + Editortemplate + related models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following models

Factory can have multiple Cars, A Car can have TypeA & TypeB

```
public class Factory
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int FactoryID {get;set;}
    //Insert properties here like Name, Location etc.
    public ICollection<Car> Cars {get;set;}
}

public class Car
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CarID {get;set;}

    public int FactoryID {get;set;}
    public Factory Factory {get;set;}

    //The Types
    public TypeA TypeA {get;set;}
    public TypeB TypeB {get;set;}
}

public class TypeA
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TypeAID {get;set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}

public class TypeB
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int TypeBID {get;set;}

    [Key, ForeignKey("Car")]
    public int CarID {get;set;}
    public Car Car {get;set;}
}
```

Which is shown in an EditorTemplate with the following

```
Factory factory = Factory factory = db.Factory.Where(f => f.FactoryID == 1)
                            .Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeA))
                            .Include(f => f.Cars.Select(c => c.TypeB)).FirstOrDefault();
```

EditorTemplate: ie - ive left out div's and labels for sake of keeping it short

```
@model project.Car
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Factory.FactoryID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.FactoryID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.CarID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TypeA.TypeAID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.TypeB.TypeBID)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarDataA)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CarDataB)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TypaA.TypeAData)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.TypaB.TypeBData)
```

I just post the model to view and so on and so forth. Then comes the time to post the data back to the model.

RootView: again stripped down

```
@model project.Factory
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cars, new { TypeList = ViewBag.TypeList })
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Save">
    </div>
}
```

My post action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FactoryEdit(Factory factory)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.entry(factory).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        //Redirect
    }
    //Return view
}
```

All data related to the Factory object is lost, except the other models data - (Car, TypeA,TypeB)
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: What does the editor template look like?

Comment: My View takes a Factory Model by the way then using an editorfor(model => model.Cars)

Comment: Do you have the relevant `HiddenFor`/`Displayfor` bits for the Factory model in the root view?

Comment: Im not showing any factory data in the root view, only in the editortemplate - do i need hiddenfor in my root view as well ?

Comment: Yes, if you need those values to be returned to your action method, then you do need them.

Comment: how would they look then? I'm not quite sure I get the whole "hidden" thing yet

Comment: Can you show the relevant parts of the root view?

Comment: Updated question again

Comment: You not rendering any controls for the properties of `Factory` (except the collection of `Car`) so nothing will post back (except the collection of `Car`). Its not good practice (and in your case not necessary) to render a lot of hidden inputs and you should consider using a view model to represent what you want to display and edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any POST back to an action method will only contain data which you explicitly specify. The editor templates you have are doing this correctly but you also need the values in the 'root' level to be passed.

This is normally done with the HiddenFor/DisplayFor/EditorFor helpers. Each of these creates an HTML `input` tag on the page which is included in your form data. So in your base view you need to include any values you need passing back. For example, a simplified version may look like this:

```
@model project.Factory
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.FactoryID )
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Cars)
}
```

This will essentially give you HTML output like this:

```
<form ....>
    <input ID='FactoryID' type='hidden' value='123'>

    <input ID='CarID' type='hidden' value='123'>
    <input ID='CarDataA' type='hidden' value='Ford'>
</form>
```

Note: The input of type hidden is solely there to be used to pass data back in the HTTP POST. Without it, the MVC engine is not able to reconstruct your `Factory` object with all of the relevant details.

Comment: So i basically need to create a hidden field for any property Im not showing as per my view?

Comment: Yes. I would suggest only returning values that are used as primary keys (i.e. the `FactoryID`) and other values that have changed.

Comment: Im getting a string conversion error when referencing something thats not a value-type - because it tries to convert from string to my class - how do i do this with hidden? or do i just find the item in the action instead and add it there instead? and how far do i go with the hidden fields when everything hsa references to everything? car.typeA.car.factory.car.typaA - or Do i just get an ID and combine my object server side?